# How does time.h clock() work under Windows?

Tags: c, timer, clock, round-robin

I am trying to create a simple queue schedule for an embedded System in C.
The idea is that within a Round Robin some functions are called based on the time constraints declared in the `Tasks[]` array.

```
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdint.h>

//Constants
#define SYS_TICK_INTERVAL   1000UL
#define INTERVAL_0MS        0
#define INTERVAL_10MS       (100000UL / SYS_TICK_INTERVAL)
#define INTERVAL_50MS       (500000UL / SYS_TICK_INTERVAL)

//Function calls
void task_1(clock_t tick);
void task_2(clock_t tick);
uint8_t get_NumberOfTasks(void);

//Define the schedule structure
typedef struct
{
    double Interval;
    double LastTick;
    void (*Function)(clock_t tick);
}TaskType;

//Creating the schedule itself
TaskType Tasks[] =
{
    {INTERVAL_10MS, 0, task_1},
    {INTERVAL_50MS, 0, task_2},
};

int main(void)
{
    //Get the number of tasks to be executed
    uint8_t task_number = get_NumberOfTasks();

    //Initializing the clocks
    for(int i = 0; i < task_number; i++)
    {
        clock_t myClock1 = clock();
        Tasks[i].LastTick = myClock1;
        printf("Task %d clock has been set to %f\n", i, myClock1);
    }

    //Round Robin
    while(1)
    {       
        //Go through all tasks in the schedule
        for(int i = 0; i < task_number; i++)
        {
            //Check if it is time to execute it
            if((Tasks[i].LastTick - clock()) > Tasks[i].Interval)
            {
                //Execute it
                clock_t myClock2 = clock();
                (*Tasks[i].Function)(myClock2);
                //Update the last tick
                Tasks[i].LastTick = myClock2;
            }
        }
        Sleep(SYS_TICK_INTERVAL);       
    }
}

void task_1(clock_t tick)
{
    printf("%f - Hello from task 1\n", tick);
}

void task_2(clock_t tick)
{
    printf("%f - Hello from task 2\n", tick);
}

uint8_t get_NumberOfTasks(void)
{
    return sizeof(Tasks) / sizeof(*Tasks);
}
```

The code compiles without a single warning, but I guess I don't understand how the command `clock()` work.

Here you can see what I get when I run the program:

```
F:\AVR Microcontroller>timer
Task 0 clock has been set to 0.000000
Task 1 clock has been set to 0.000000
```

I tried changing `Interval` and `LastTick` from float to double just to make sure this was not a precision error, but still it does not work.

Comment: At least one less obvious bug beyond the obvious one, clock() always increments.  So Tasks[i].LastTick - clock() is backwards and produces a negative number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`%f` is not the right formatting specifier to print out `myClock1` as `clock_t` is likely not `double`. You shouldn't assume that `clock_t` is `double`. If you want to print `myClock1` as a floating point number you have to manually convert it to `double`:

```
printf("Task %d clock has been set to %f\n", i, (double)myClock1);
```

Alternatively, use the macro `CLOCKS_PER_SEC` to turn `myClock1` into a number of seconds:

```
printf("Task %d clock has been set to %f seconds\n", i,
    (double)myClock1 / CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
```

Additionally, your subtraction in the scheduler loop is wrong. Think about it: `clock()` grows larger with the time, so `Tasks[i].LastTick - clock()` always yields a negative value. I think you want `clock() - Tasks[i].LastTick` instead.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. It shows the same results as before though. :-/

Comment: Try to add strategic `printf()` calls to figure out what's happening.

Comment: Ah! I think your subtraction is the wrong way round. It should be `clock() - Tasks[i].LastTick > Tasks[i].Interval` as `clock()` grows larger with time.

Comment: That should be (double)myClock1 / CLOCKS_PER_SEC, not the other way around.

Answer (score 1):

The behavior of the `clock` function is depending on the operating system. On Windows it basically runs of the wall clock, while on e.g. Linux it's the process CPU time.

Also, the result of `clock` by itself is useless, it's only use is in comparison between two clocks (e.g. `clock_end - clock_start`).

Finally, the `clock_t` type (which `clock` returns) is an *integer* type, you only get floating point values if you cast a difference (as the one above) to e.g. `double` and divide by `CLOCKS_PER_SEC`. Attempting to print a `clock_t` using the `"%f"` format will lead to *undefined behavior*.

Reading [a `clock` reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4e2ess30.aspx) might help.

Comment: But OP is comparing the difference between two clock calls.

Comment: @FUZxxl True, but the OP doesn't print the difference.